# How work the test in laravel with model route

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, php-8

How best to build with testing this way.

I would like to test everything to the point of no return. Now I just want to select a BillingDetail for this I have the route

```
Route::post('/user/billingDetail/select/{billingDetail}', [BillingDetailController::class, 'select'])->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->name('user.billingDetail.select');
```

and here once my test I have tried:

```
public function test_can_user_select_billing_detail_as_default() {
    $response = $this->actingAs(self::$user)->post('/user/billingDetail/select/', [self::$billingDetail]);
    $response->assertSuccessful();
}
```

the problem here is that the route needs a {billingDetail} but what should I do, I have to pass it with how can I do that best. The route needs the model BillingDetail.

Answer (score 0):

there are various ways to do it, according to me you can:

1. create the billing detail in your setUp function in order to make it usable by multiple tests in that test class.
2. add the billing detail to a protected property of the class extended by your test class, (Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase in Laravel), and then use that property in your tests.
3. use a dataProvider, if you have multiple billing details.
4. do as you did, but remember that the parameter should be like
   `['billingDetail' => $yourBillingDetail].`

you can persist a faked billing detail with a factory

```
BillingDetail::factory()->create()
```